# How to setup for jQuery-File-Upload? How to implement the upload handler?

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, file-upload, flask

I am new on Javascript. However I want to implement the jquery plugin for File uploading.

Here is the [setup guide](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup) I found but I have no basic knowledge on how to setup this.

I am using python (flask) as my server side implementation

From the setup guide heading,

**Using jQuery File Upload (UI version) with a custom server-side upload handler**

I have no idea on how to setup point 1, 4, 5

for 1, what is a upload handler? and how to implement in python (flask)?

for 4, what doses "Upload the jQuery-File-Upload folder to your website."??? what is it use for?

and for 5, I have to return a JSON response on the upload handler? Why we have to do that?

The setup is quite complicated...anyone can give me some hints?

Kit

Comment: There's a server side tutorial with flask at https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Flask

Comment: This one is already a old version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe one or two hints:

1. The upload handler is simply a URL endpoint that the jQuery File Upload can send files to - it needs to be able to handle incoming HTTP requests.

   ```
   @app.route("/uploads", methods=["GET", "POST"])
   def upload_handler():
       # Handle the upload here
       pass
   ```
2. You don't need to upload the *entire* folder - only the CSS and JavaScript you will be using.  If you only need file uploading your template could look like the [basic setup](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin).  (However, you should minify and concatenate your files for a deployed website).
3. You return a JSON response to the upload handler so that the script handler performing the XHR file upload request can know things like:

   - What the URL for the uploaded image is (and the thumbnail, if you are making thumbnails).
   - What the delete URL (and method) is.

The [linked example for Flask](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Flask) seems very similar to the [Django example for the new version](https://github.com/miki725/Django-jQuery-File-Uploader-Integration-demo/blob/master/upload/views.py) - you can probably start with that and then patch it to work with the new version of jQuery file upload.

Comment: Sean: Thx. How about the progress bar? Do I need to add extra code to handles the staus of the upload status?

Comment: @KitHo - looking at the code I'd say no - it looks like the progress bar is only available for browsers that support providing the progress on the client. See: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/js/jquery.fileupload.js#L213